# Masking With Phone Number Formats With Spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I have already a code that format it to the correct number format but the problem is
1.The position of the number input after the first and second hyphen don't have correct position. Sample. When i Input 12345 after the first (-) it will be 123465 The position got swap.
2. The user cannot add in the middle of the number if it already reach the maximum number which. What is happening right now is if i click on the middle of the text box i can add numbers and all the last parts are replaced.

[JSFIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/pgsawnk3/926/)

HTML + JS

```
Telephone: <input type="text" value="____-___-___" data-mask="____-___-___"/><br/>

 Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll("*[data-mask]"), applyDataMask);

function applyDataMask(field) {
var mask = field.dataset.mask.split('');

// For now, this just strips everything that's not a number
function stripMask(maskedData) {
    function isDigit(char) {
        return /\d/.test(char);
    }
    return maskedData.split('').filter(isDigit);
}

// Replace `_` characters with characters from `data`
function applyMask(data) {
    return mask.map(function(char) {
        if (char != '_') return char;
        if (data.length == 0) return char;
        return data.shift();
    }).join('')
}

function reapplyMask(data) {
    return applyMask(stripMask(data));
}

function changed() {   
    var oldStart = field.selectionStart;
    var oldEnd = field.selectionEnd;

    field.value = reapplyMask(field.value);

    field.selectionStart = oldStart;
    field.selectionEnd = oldEnd;

}

field.addEventListener('click', changed)
field.addEventListener('keyup', changed)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

> ```
> <input id="txtPhone" data-mask="(___) ___-____" type="text" />
> ```

Javascript:

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll("*[data-mask]"), applyDataMask);

 function applyDataMask(field) {

    var mask = field.dataset.mask.split('');

    // For now, this just strips everything that's not a number
    function stripMask(maskedData) {
        function isDigit(char) {
            return /\d/.test(char);
        }
        return maskedData.split('').filter(isDigit);
    }

    // Replace `_` characters with characters from `data`
    function applyMask(data) {
        return mask.map(function (char) {
            if (char != '_') return char;
            if (data.length == 0) return char;
            return data.shift();
        }).join('')
    }

    function reapplyMask(data) {
        return applyMask(stripMask(data));
    }

    function changed(e) {
        var i = field.value.indexOf('_');
        if (e.keyCode == undefined) {
            i = 0;
        }
        field.value = reapplyMask(field.value);
        field.selectionStart = i;
        field.selectionEnd = i;
    }

    field.addEventListener('click', changed)
    field.addEventListener('keyup', changed);
}
```